# Find first distinct string

Tags: string

I was having an interview for an internship. Interviewer asked following question.

**Given a stream of Strings, find the first distinct string(not repeated in stream).**

For ex : "abc","xyz","abcd","abc"

ans is "abc","abc","abc","xyz"

I told the approach with map and sets, but the time complexity is O(nlogn) assuming String's hash value is calculated in O(1). He constantly kept emphasizing to do better and told that the expected complexity is O(n). I could not come up with solution and I was rejected. Please help me with an appraoch.

Comment: i was thinking trie and google turned up this : [Count of distinct substrings of a string using Suffix Trie](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-distinct-substrings-string-using-suffix-trie/)

Comment: Well how about using LinkedHashSet, it would maintain insertion order of elements, and checking for containing and adding would be constant. So complexity would be O(n)

Comment: @Thomas I don't think that he was expecting me knowing suffix trie. There might be simple approach.

Comment: @Ajris complexity of map is O(n) in worst case. It is not O(1) for adding.

Comment: Well, i think you are talking about set. It all depends whether you would implement your own equals and hashcode method or depend on the one already implemented. You usually dont talk that its O(n), its O(1), its optimized like a lot, so in most times you dont need to worry that it would rise to O(n), especially in this one

Comment: Just to assure you, in docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html




'Like HashSet, it provides constant-time performance for the basic operations (add, contains and remove), assuming the hash function disperses elements properly among the buckets.'

Comment: @Ajris I know that it is amortized O(1) but he was still considering O(log(n)) and I think that we must consider worst case. I also gave approach of map but he wasn't satisfied.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178474/discussion-between-ajris-and-parth-patel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be solved with trie and queue.

```
for string in text:
    if string not in trie:
        insert_in_trie(string)
        insert_in_queue(string)
    else:
        if not queue.empty():
            queue.pop()

    if queue.empty():
        print("No distinct character")
    else:
        print(queue.front())
```

Overall complexity will O(total length of strings) because insertion, deletion and peek in queue and trie will be O(length of string).

Comment: I think that this approach won't work. Consider example : "abc","123","abc". We can modify your approach by maintaining frequency of string at leaf node of trie. if(freqency of string is more than one) don't push in queue else push in queue.Now for quering,check the frequency to first string in queue by going to that leaf node. if it is more than one(poll from queue) else print that string. This will work in amortized O(n+length of strings) where n is number of strings but we can't say that  query can be done in O(1).